# Filling a dataframe from a starting value to a stop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Dataframe containing security prices like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr

gld = pd.DataFrame(pdr.get_data_yahoo('GLD')['Close'])

gld['returns'] = np.log(gld['Close']).diff()
gld['ma'] = gld['Close'].rolling(21).mean()
gld['ratio'] = gld['Close'] / gld['ma']
```

When the ratio reaches a threshold value, in this case the 90th percentile I will fill a -1. I would like to continue filling -1 until gld.ratio drops below 1. We repeat this process for the 10th percentile, filling with 1 until the ratio reaches 1 again. For the remaining values I want to fill 0. I can get pretty close to fill ing -1 correctly with something like this:

```
p = np.percentile(gld['ratio'].dropna(),[10, 90])
gld['position'] = np.where(gld['ratio'] > p[1], -1, np.nan)
gld['position'] = np.where(gld['ratio'] < p[0], 1, gld['position'])
gld['position'] = np.where(np.logical_and(gld.shift() == -1, gld.ratio > 1),
                           -1, gld.position)
```

My idea was to look and see if the row above has -1 and if gld.ratio is still above 1. The limitation here is when you have multiple rows that still need to be filled; both conditions do not hold for more than one row.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: maybe you should create normal function which can use global variables to keep previous values and run it with `.apply()`